# Can't get Chartist legend plugin to work

Tags: meteor, chartist.js

I've got the mfpierre:chartist meteor package installed and the mspi:chartistlegend plugin for it installed (both atmosphere packages). I've got the plugin like so:

```
new Chartist.Bar('.ct-chart', {
  labels: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
  series: [
    [1,2,3,4], 
    [1,2,3,4],  
    [1,2,3,4] 
  ]
}, {
  plugins: [ Chartist.plugins.legend() ]

});
```

The chart won't render with the "plugins" key/value pair in place. If I remove the "plugins" key/value, the chart renders fine. As far as I can tell, I'm following the documentation. Any help welcome.

Comment: Console gives, "TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'Chartist.plugins.legend')"

Answer (score 9):

I am not using meteor so your mileage may vary but I am using Angular2 and was getting similar errors.  The answer for me was to use the legend plugin to get it initialized first and then use it in the Chartist plugin definition like you have done. This feels hacky but its working...

```
import * as Chartist from 'chartist';
import * as MyLegend from 'chartist-plugin-legend';

constructor(){
  var tester = new MyLegend(); //without this line, you get 'Chartist.plugins undefined'
}

.... in another method like ngOnInit or something...
new Chartist.Bar('.ct-chart', {
  labels: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
  series: [
    [1,2,3,4], 
    [1,2,3,4],  
    [1,2,3,4] 
  ]
}, {
  plugins: [ Chartist.plugins.legend({
        legendNames: ['Blue pill', 'Red pill', 'Purple pill']
    }) ]

});
```

Comment: yikes, a downvote for working code on a question with no answer marked, someone feeling grumpy today?

Comment: where is `tester` used after declaration?

Comment: @Gel tester is not used after declaration at all.  It just instantiates the legend and if you don't do that you get an error. hacky but working.

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide an object to `.legend()` containing names for the legends, like this:

```
new Chartist.Line('.ct-chart-line', {
    labels: ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday'],
    series: [
        [12, 9, 7, 8, 5],
        [2, 1, 3.5, 7, 3],
        [1, 3, 4, 5, 6]
     ]
}, {
    fullWidth: true,
    chartPadding: {
        right: 40
    },
    plugins: [
        Chartist.plugins.legend({
            legendNames: ['Blue pill', 'Red pill', 'Purple pill'],
        })
    ]
});
```

More demos here: https://codeyellowbv.github.io/chartist-plugin-legend/

Comment: Thanks, Khang, although the object isn't needed and doesn't fix the issue.

Comment: when you provide the object, do you see any new error messages?

Answer (score 0):

You can also add names in the series like this:

```
series: [
    { "name": "Money A", "data": [60000, 40000, 80000, 70000] },
    { "name": "Money B", "data": [40000, 30000, 70000, 65000] },
    { "name": "Money C", "data": [8000, 3000, 10000, 6000] }
]
```

[Source](https://codeyellowbv.github.io/chartist-plugin-legend/)