# Chartist is not defined in Threshold Plugin in Nuxt

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, chartist.js

I'm trying to follow the advice from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40484994/typeerror-chartist-plugins-legend-is-not-a-function) to utilize [this threshold plugin](https://github.com/gionkunz/chartist-plugin-threshold) and am getting "Chartist is not defined".

I am not certain how to replicate a constructor in Vue/Nuxt so I am not sure if that is the reason that I am getting the error or if that post is not a good fit for what I want to do.

Here is my code snippet:

```
<template>    
    <div class="ct-chart"></div>
</template>

    <script>
        import Chartist from 'chartist'
        import * as Threshold from 'chartist-plugin-threshold'
        ...

        export default {

        mounted() {
            var threshold = Threshold()
            new Chartist.Line(
                '.ct-chart',
                 ...
                 plugins: [
                        Chartist.plugins.ctThreshold({
                            threshold: 4,
                        }),
                    ],
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you use the [vue-chartist](https://github.com/Yopadd/vue-chartist) package instead that is specially created to work seamlessly with Vue.

To install it run the following command:

```
npm install vue-chartist
```

To make it work in Nuxt you should add it as a plugin in the `plugins` folder. So in case you create a `vue-chartist.js` file for example it should be something like this:

```js
import Vue from 'vue'

Vue.use(require('vue-chartist'))
```

and then you would have to add it to your `nuxt.config.js` file:

```js
plugins: ['@/plugins/vue-chartist.js']
```

After that you can use it through the `chartist` component:

```js
<chartist
    ratio="ct-major-second"
    type="Line"
    :data="chartData"
    :options="chartOptions" >
</chartist>
```

Check the link at the top for more info.